# How to get the list of attachments (notes) related to an EmailTemplate in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM Enterprise, Version 8.1.0 (Build 135) (Summer '18), the **cloud** version and I need, from an external site, to get the list of all EmailTemplates and for earch EmailTemplate the list of its attachments (or Notes), via the API.

I can list all EmailTemplates but can't find, for each of them, the list of attached files, what do I have to do (with the API)?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We are always glad to help and support, but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Jon Skeet's SO Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @Sanguinary, I'm searching for the API to use not an example of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the Filter API on the Notes module to get the attachments for each EmailTemplate.
This is the only way I found so far, as using the "attachments" link in EmailTemplates did not yield any results...

Example: `POST` request to `/rest/v11_2/Notes/filter` with following payload:

```
{
    max_num: 1000,
    fields: ["id", "name"], /* specify the fields you want to receive */
    filter: [
        {"email_id": "<id of the email template goes here>"},
    ],
}
```

For more info regarding the filter API see "`POST /<module>/filter`" at `<sugar_site>/rest/v11_2/help`

Notes:

- In older versions of Sugar (before Sugar 8) the relationship looked different, so the filter there should look like this: `{filter: [{parent_type:"Emails", parent_id: "<id of the email template goes here>"}]}`

Comment: Thank you very much Jay, that's exactly what I was searching for!